# Match multiple groups in any order with unknown text in between

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Example: [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/Ha3ehm/1/)

I have some text as follows:

```
M=NS MAX=[5,10,20,20] A=4 MIN=[1,1,1,20] R=1 S=1 T=3 D=2 

M=NS MAX=[5,10,20,20] MIN=[1,1,1,20] R=1 S=1 T=3 A=4 D=2 

M=NS MAX=[5,10,20,20] Z=123 MIN=[1,1,1,20] R=1 S=1 T=3 A=4 D=2
```

And I have my regex:

```
^(?:\w*M=(?P<M>\w+)
|\s+S=(?P<S>[\d,]+)
|\s+C=(?P<C>[\d,]+)
|\s+MAX=\[(?P<MAX>[\d,]+)\]
|\s+MIN=\[(?P<MIN>[\d,]+)\]
|\s+A=(?P<A>\d+)
|\sR=(?P<R>[\d,]+))+.*?$
```

The regex works pretty well, however, I'm stuck on the last part of this question. The regex works for any order of the terms I'm looking for, but as soon as there is an additional term in the middle, that isn't also checked for as a group (such as `Z=123` on line 3), then it breaks.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I guess you could add a generic option, like `|\s+\w+=\S+`. [See your mofified example here](https://regex101.com/r/Ha3ehm/2).

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest going generic, since [`^(?:\w*M=(?P<M>\w+)|\s+S=(?P<S>[\d,]+)|\s+C=(?P<C>[\d,]+)|\s+MAX=\[(?P<MAX>[\d,]+)\]|\s+MIN=\[(?P<MIN>[\d,]+)\]|\s+A=(?P<A>\d+)|\s+R=(?P<SCEN>[\d,]+)|\s++(?!(?:M(?:AX|IN)?|[SCAR])=)\w+=\w+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/Ha3ehm/4) does not look sane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a generic alternation, like

```
|\s+\w+=\S+.
```

It's matches space(s) followed by a number (one or more) of word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`), then the equal sign and finally a number of non space characters.

[See your modified example here](https://regex101.com/r/Ha3ehm/2).

Answer (score 1):

I might be trumped here, but couldn't you use a generic expression for **all of your key/value pairs** ? At the time being, all of your examples could be matched by

```
(?P<key>\b[A-Z]+\b) # key group
\h*=\h*             # spaces, = spaces
(?P<value>          # value group
    (\[)?           # if the first char is a [
        (?(3).*?\]  # ... look for ]
        |           # else
        \w+         # [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    )
)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zjJSvf/2).

Comment: You were just pipped to the post, but I do like the breakdown you've given here.